# Send Bulk Email in VB.NET Reciepients Emails will uploaded by excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, email

This was the code I used to send emails to my clients.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1
    Dim file(2) As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
        smtpserver.Host = TextBox3.Text
        smtpserver.Port = TextBox4.Text
        mail = New MailMessage
        mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text)
        mail.To.Add(TextBox5.Text)
        mail.To.Add(TextBox12.Text)
        mail.Subject = TextBox6.Text
        mail.Body = TextBox10.Text
        If Not TextBox7.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(TextBox7.Text)
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
        End If
        If Not TextBox8.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(TextBox8.Text)
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
        End If
        If Not TextBox9.Text = Nothing Then
            Dim attach As New Attachment(TextBox9.Text)
            mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
        End If
        smtpserver.EnableSsl = True
        Try
            smtpserver.Send(mail)
        Catch ex As SmtpException
            MsgBox("either you typed something wrong or something is wrong with the program...most likely it was something you typed so try again")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        file = Nothing
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        file = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
        TextBox7.Text = file(0)
        Try
            TextBox8.Text = file(1)
        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException
        End Try
        Try
            TextBox9.Text = file(2)
        Catch ex As IndexOutOfRangeException

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Here I can only send emails, which are in those two textboxes, but I need to send more to the 20 customers whose emails were stored in an excel file.

Comment: You need to read the details from an excel file - have you tried that?

Answer (score 4):

Off the top of my head

```
' Create new Application.
Dim excel As Application = New Application

' Open Excel spreadsheet.
Dim w As Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\file.xls")

' Loop over all sheets.
For i As Integer = 1 To w.Sheets.Count

    ' Get sheet.
    Dim sheet As Worksheet = w.Sheets(i)

    ' Get range.
    Dim r As Range = sheet.UsedRange

    ' Load all cells into 2d array.
    Dim array(,) As Object = r.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)

    ' Scan the cells.
    If array IsNot Nothing Then 

    ' Get bounds of the array.
    Dim bound0 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim bound1 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(1)  


    ' Loop over all elements.
    For j As Integer = 1 To bound0
        For x As Integer = 1 To bound1
        Dim address As String = array(j, x)

                     'Send your email to **address** here

        Next

    Next
    End If
Next

' Close.
w.Close()
```

Comment: Wow!! Great Thanks. I am a beginners. I am just confused to import receiver emails only from excel please...

Comment: As a word of caution, you'll want to look at explicitly cleaning up your Excel objects. .NET does handle them well. Call `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` on all Excel objects, e.g. workbook, worksheet, range.